# grey out a complete slide on beamer

Tags: beamer, highlighting

I mad a bloc in front of other content. Now i want to not highlight the slide like shown in the picture bellow. How can i do that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A quick and easy way is to use `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\begin{onlyenv}<2->
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[black,opacity=0.5] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east); 
    \node[draw=orange,fill=black,font=\Huge\color{orange}] at (current page.center) {Some text};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{onlyenv}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]